Any way to get Vscode cpp extension to hint calculated static const in a function like it calculates globals?
In Vscode C++ with the popular Microsoft C/C++ plugins, global consts get calculated into type hints, for example here you see that 100 / 50 is 2:


But if I do the same thing within a function with static consts, I don't get the calculated result:

Is there any way to modify the extension to calculate these? It would just make sense to do so.

Works for me with the clangd extension.

if these are compile-time constants, are you using a language standard and compiler version that supports constexpr?
